# jQuery: read input value without clicking

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to read an input file if it's empty or not and then return an error message. The code seems to not work

```
$(function() {
   $("#fname").load(function(e) {
    var fname = $(this).val(); 
    $.post('../includes/check-fname.php', {'fname': fname}, 
    function(data) { 
       $("#append").html(data); 
    });
  });
});
```

However, if I use keyup, click, blur event triggers it returns the data. But yea, how can I trigger the ajax after loading?

Comment: What is #fname element? If input, INPUT doesn't have an onload event

Comment: @A.Wolff is an input text field or <input class="form" id="fname" type="text" name="fname" /> Edit: Ah, thanks for telling me. Are there other ways?

Comment: But then what do you expect here, INPUT type text has no onload event. Just remove this onload handler

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    $.post('../includes/check-fname.php', {fname: fname},
    function(data) {
        $("#append").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: ready pseudo handler must be attached to document object only, even an empty object will fire it

Comment: `$('#fname').val();` ;) +1 I understand it like this too